# How to get only the user's data from firestore rather than all data in the collection?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a flutter app that allows users to log into an account and then store contact details in a firebase firestore. It currently shows the contact details for all registered accounts. I want the user to be able to see only their own contact details and not others, and I can't figure out how to do this.

When added on the collection reference definition line, using `.where()` is returning:

> A value of type 'Query<Map<String, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'CollectionReference<Object?>'.

[image: Database structure]

```
class DatabaseService {

  final String ?uid;
  DatabaseService({ this.uid });

  //  collection reference
  final CollectionReference contactsCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('contacts');

  Future updateUserData(String name, String phone) async {
    return await contactsCollection.doc(uid).set({
      'name': name,
      'phone': phone,
    });
  }

  // contacts list from snapshot

  List<Contacts> _contactsListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc){
      return Contacts(
        phone: doc.get('phone') ?? 0,
        name: doc.get('name') ?? ''
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  // userData from snapshot
  UserData _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return UserData(
      uid: uid,
      name: snapshot['name'],
      phone: snapshot['phone'],
    );
  }

  //  get contacts stream
  Stream<List<Contacts>> get contacts {
    return contactsCollection.snapshots()
      .map(_contactsListFromSnapshot);
  }

  // get user doc stream
  Stream<UserData> get userData {
    return contactsCollection.doc(uid).snapshots()
        .map(_userDataFromSnapshot);
  }

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.where` as follows:

```dart
  Stream<List<Contacts>> get contacts {
    return contactsCollection
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: uid)
        .snapshots()
        .map(_contactsListFromSnapshot);
  }
```

However, you should make sure that the fields have a `uid`:

```dart
Future updateUserData(String name, String phone) async {
    return await contactsCollection.doc(uid).set({
      'uid': uid, // --> add this
      'name': name,
      'phone': phone,
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

That error message seems correct, as calling `where` on a `CollectionReference` gives you back a `Query`. The simplest fix is to make the field implicitly type with *just* `final`:

```
final contactsCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('contacts').where(...);
```

---

After that, I'm not sure what you want to filter on though, as the two fields showing in the screenshot (`name` and `phone`) don't associate the document with a specific user as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future, here's my full solution. I needed to get the user id directly from firebase.

```
import 'package:app_v1/models/contacts.dart';
import 'package:app_v1/models/myuser.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

final User? user = auth.currentUser;
final id = user?.uid;


class DatabaseService {

  final String ?uid;
  DatabaseService({ this.uid });

  //  collection reference
  final CollectionReference contactsCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('contacts');

  Future updateUserData(String name, String phone) async {
    return await contactsCollection.doc(uid).set({
      'uid': uid,
      'name': name,
      'phone': phone,
    });
  }

  // contacts list from snapshot

  List<Contacts> _contactsListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc){
      return Contacts(
          phone: doc.get('phone') ?? 0,
          name: doc.get('name') ?? ''
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  // userData from snapshot
  UserData _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return UserData(
      uid: uid,
      name: snapshot['name'],
      phone: snapshot['phone'],
    );
  }

  //  get contacts stream
  Stream<List<Contacts>> get contacts {
    return contactsCollection
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: id)
        .snapshots()
        .map(_contactsListFromSnapshot);
  }

  // get user doc stream
  Stream<UserData> get userData {
    return contactsCollection.doc(uid).snapshots()
        .map(_userDataFromSnapshot);
  }

}
```

Sorry if not formatted correctly.